# Formalising compound sentences in truth-functional logic.

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I have the sentence:

> "If it's the case that if the Butler was guilty then the
>   Chambermaid was guilty then it's not the case that the Butler was
>   guilty but the Chambermaid wasn't."

This needs to be formalised in truth-functional logic.

Let:

> p: the Butler was guilty
>
> q: the Chambermaid was guilty

Would this be formalised in the following manner:

> (p → q) → ¬ (p & ¬ q)

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is there another negation missing?

Comment: That's a sentence that no actual human would ever produce _except by_ "translating" a propositional formula into mock English. Your task doesn't have **anything** to do with formalizing natural English, but is merely to figure out what the original propositional formula that produced this abomination must have been.

Comment: @HenningMakholm my lecturer wouldn't be happy to hear that ^.^

Comment: @Moritz Yes there was, I've changed it now on the post to: (p → q) → ¬ (p & ¬ q)

Comment: @Andy: Tough for him.

Comment: @Andy: I think you have got it right now. By the way: since $p \to q$ is logically equivalent with $\neg(p \wedge \neg q)$, you have actually found $(p \to q) \to (p \to q)$.

Comment: @Moritz Fantastic thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've missed a negation. Your sentence translates as "If (If the Butler was guilty then the Chambermaid was guilty) then it isn't the case that (the Butler was guilty and the Chambermaid was guilty)". In other words, you've changed the "wasn't" at the end of your target sentence into "was, too".

Comment: I've changed it to (p → q) → ¬ (p & ¬ q) does this look better?

Comment: Yep, that's right.

Comment: Thanks! So then what is the difference between (p → q) → ¬ (p & ¬ q) and (p → q) →  (¬p &  q) because the logic tables are different but I can't see how in English they would be any different. (i.e. they would mean the same thing right?)

Comment: Not remotely. $\neg(p \& \neg q)$ says "It is not the case that BOTH the Butler is guilty AND the Chambermaid is not" - i.e., we don't know who did it, but we know that it can't be that the Butler did it and the Chambermaid wasn't in on it. But it's possible that someone else entirely is guilty. $\neg p \& q$ says "the Butler is not guilty and the Chambermaid is guilty" - we know exactly who did it!

Comment: Yes that makes sense. I've looked over the De Morgan's laws and I think my misunderstanding stemmed from my lecturer not covering this! Much clearer now.